# Banner calling notification like WhatsApp video call in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, voip, whatsapp

My app is a VOIP app. and it was working fine before apple restricted to trigger CallKit as soon as VOIP is received.

Before this limitation i was receiving the call alert as VOIP and was repeatedly creating a local notification which was achieving the goal.

To cater the case i tried the following:

- **Silent notifications**:
  These works fine only when the app is in foreground. In background i receive a silent push but can't play the sound using

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(url as CFURL, &mySound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(mySound, {
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(self.mySound);
});
```

also the silent push is not received when the app is in killed state.

- **Notification Service Extension**:
  I have also tried to trigger my repeated local notification in this extension but was not able to do that as the notification extension scope is not in the app.

Is there any way to trigger a function of application when notification extension is triggered irrespective of what is the state of app e.g (killed, background, foreground, suspended)?

Any help will be appreciated to move on from here.

[Need to achieve this repeated ringer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us8hF.png)

Comment: Why not just use CallKit as Apple requires - You get the benefit of better integration with the native calling system

Comment: @Paulw11 i we have 2 types of calls in our app one is very critical and important for that i use CallKit, but for the other type of call which is not as much important as the first 1 for that the requirement is to show this type of banner ringer.

Comment: That isn't an option any more if you want to use a VoIP push.  I believe that WhatsApp currently has an exemption to the new requirement but that will probably change (if it hasn't already) once they have developed replacement code.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you please guide is there any possibility to this?

Is there any way to trigger a function of application when notification extension is triggered irrespective of what is the state of app e.g (killed, background, foreground, suspended)?

Comment: Pushkit (VoIP push) is the only push notification that will be delivered to your app if it  killed.  That means you need to comply with the CallKit requirements or accept the fact that a repeated notification isn't possible if the app is killed.  You can still send a standard push that will be displayed as a banner for the user to action.

Comment: @Paulw11 i agree with you on this, but i can also update data from notification extension, but as per my knowledge in that case the updated data can be fetched when app will again open. i am curious to know that is there any way i trigger my app to be open from notification service extension?

Comment: The app is only opened if the user taps on your notification banner